# UIImagePNGRepresentation() has been replaced by .pngdata()

Tags: ios, swift, swift5

In Xcode 10 `UIImagePNGRepresention()` worked ,but in the new Xcode it changed to .pngData() . And I'm not sure how to use the new instance method properly.

I'm trying to convert a `UIImage` to `NSData` and not sure how to do that on `.pngData()`
This is how I did it on the old `UIImagePNGRepresentation()`:

```
let imageData:NSData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image!)! as NSData
```

I want to know how to do that ^ in the new intance method

Comment: Don't use `NSData`. Use Swift native `Data` type and unwrap it safely. Not all images can be converted to `Data`, therefore that method `pngData` might return nil: `if let imageData = image?.pngData() {`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply:

```
let imageData = image!.pngData()! as NSData
```

See [UIImage.pngData()](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimage/1624096-pngdata)

Answer (score 2):

.pngData() function returns data object containing png data or nil.

So you can use this function in the following way:

let imageData = image!.pngData()!

See https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimage/1624096-pngdata